# How to use jsonbuilder to make a json which has a key named like a DefaultGroovyMethods method (identity)?

Tags: groovy, jsonbuilder

```
def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
        def root = builder.auth {
            identity {
                    methods (['password'])
                    password {
                        user {
                            name {
                                usrName
                                domain {
                                    id usrDomain
                                }
                                password "openstack"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    scope {
                        project {
                            name prjName
                            domain {
                                id 'default'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        assert builder.toString() == '{"auth":{"identity":{"methods":["password"],"password": {"user":{"name":"admin","domain":{"id":"default"},"password":"openstack"}}},"scope":{"project":{"name":"admin","domain":{"id":"default"}}}}}'
```

assert output:

```
    Assertion failed: 

    assert builder.toString() == '{"auth":{"identity":{"methods":["password"],"password": {"user":{"name":"admin","domain":{"id":"default"},"password":"openstack"}}},"scope":{"project":{"name":"admin","domain":{"id":"default"}}}}}'
           |       |          |
           |       |          false
           |       '{"auth":{"methods":["password"],"password":{"user":{"name":{"domain":{"id":"Default"},"password":"openstack"}}},"scope":{"project":{"name":"admin","domain":{"id":"default"}}}}}'
           {"auth":{"methods":["password"],"password":{"user":{"name":{"domain":{"id":"Default"},"password":"openstack"}}},"scope":{"project":{"name":"admin","domain":{"id":"default"}}}}}
```

Basically the "identity" key is ignored.
I have seen that there is a method called "identity" belonging to DefaultGroovyMethods, but I have no ideea how to overcome this. 
First time writing Groovy, have a little background in Python. Any help is apreciated!

Complete solution done with Szymon Stepniak's answer (and other corrections to json declaration):

```
def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
    builder auth: [
            identity: {
                methods(['password'])
                password {
                    user {
                        name "$usrName"
                        domain {
                            id usrDomain
                        }
                        password "openstack"

                    }
                }
            },
            scope: {
                project {
                    name prjName
                    domain {
                        id 'default'
                        }
                    }
            }
                ]
    assert builder.toString() == '{"auth":{"identity":{"methods":["password"],"password":{"user":{"name":"admin","domain":{"id":"default"},"password":"openstack"}}},"scope":{"project":{"name":"admin","domain":{"id":"default"}}}}}'
```

Just in case someone wants to follow along this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To overcome this limitation (closure passed to `JsonBuilder.call()` method resolves `identity` method in the delegation chain), you will need to either represent your JSON document as a map or at least use a map up to `identity` key and from this place you can use a closure.

```groovy
def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()

builder auth: [
    identity: {
        methods (['password'])
        password {
            user {
                name {
                    usrName
                    domain {
                        id usrDomain
                    }
                    password "openstack"
                }
            }
        }
        scope {
            project {
                name prjName
                domain {
                    id 'default'
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Also, keep in mind that the closure you defined does not produce the expected JSON string, but it will have `identity` key that you are missing in the closure example.

Comment: That definetely answers the question. Tanks! Now i'm back to getting the json right.